# R: how to create a matrix given a basis and a set of dimensions

Tags: r, matrix

```
make_basis <- function(k, p = 10) replace(numeric(p), k, 1)
width <- 4
index <- 1
len <- 3
vec <- make_basis(index, len)
> vec
[1] 1 0 0
```

`vec` is a unit vector of length `len`. I want to populate a matrix with dimensions `(width * len) x len` with `vec` repeated `width` times and 0 everywhere else. That is, I want something that looks like this:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
 [1,]    1    0    0    0
 [2,]    0    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    0    0    0
 [4,]    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    0    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    0    0
 [7,]    0    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    0    0    0
 [9,]    0    0    0    0
[10,]    0    0    0    1
[11,]    0    0    0    0
[12,]    0    0    0    0
```

Here is another example:

```
width <- 4
index <- 2
len <- 2
vec <- make_basis(index, len)
> vec
[1] 0 1
```

The desired matrix is:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    0    0    0    0
[2,]    1    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0
[6,]    0    0    1    0
[7,]    0    0    0    0
[8,]    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function :

```
create_matrix <- function(index, width, len) {
  n <- width * len
  val <- seq_len(n)
  sapply(seq(index, n, len), function(x) as.integer(val == x))
}

create_matrix(1, 4, 3)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    0    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0
# [4,]    0    1    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0
# [6,]    0    0    0    0
# [7,]    0    0    1    0
# [8,]    0    0    0    0
# [9,]    0    0    0    0
#[10,]    0    0    0    1
#[11,]    0    0    0    0
#[12,]    0    0    0    0

create_matrix(2, 4, 2)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    0    0    0    0
#[2,]    1    0    0    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0
#[4,]    0    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    1    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    0
#[8,]    0    0    0    1
```